# webkitTransform is not working on ios Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I have a Phonegap application where I have to rotate my IMG arrow with "counter" increment. This code was working fine on semulator 4.2 and later with phonegap 1.0.0. Now I have phonegap 1.4.1 and simulator 5.0 and 5.1. Why Rotation is not happening.

document.getElementById("userguideArrow").style.webkitTransform='rotate('+counter+'deg)';

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is your counter alerting any number?

Comment: Yes counter return valid increment.

Comment: Try: elem.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate("+ counter +"deg);";

Comment: I tried zvona, but it seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

Strange issue :S... I made it work using the following:

```
var str = new String('rotate(' + counter + 'deg)');
document.getElementById("userguideArrow").style['-webkit-transform'] = str;
```

It worked for me using iPhone 5 simulator.

Hope this will work for you too. Let me know about your result mate.

Comment: Hi Littm, the above code works only when I add -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; why we need to add this in the css file for ID "userguideArrow". Even in the previous version of semulator, it works fine without adding -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

Comment: Actualy I really don't know... sorry mate XD lol. When I tried the code above, I didn't add/modify additional CSS or else. In fact, it's strange behavior: when using 'static' value it works (eg: `el.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(45deg)";`) while using dynamic values (eg: `el.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate("+ counter +"deg)";`) just make it not work O__o... Actually, I also don't understand... :S I think this could be another interesting SO question I guess ^^ (myself, I'll be curious to know why it's behaving so :) )